# Write variables to file as %VAR% not as the value of the variable in BAT

Tags: batch-file, command, cmd, boot

Write variables to file as %VAR% not as the value of the variable, as well ask making tasklist function properly when redirecting output.

Code im using to write to file:

```
echo tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %ZOEXT%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%ZOEXT%">NUL >> boot.bat
echo if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" start /d "%ZODIR%" %ZOEXT% >> boot.bat
```

Result:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Zoiper.exe"  
if "0"=="1" start /d "C:\Documents and Settings\mgladman\Desktop\Zoip\Zoiper Communicator\" Zoiper.exe
```

What I want added to boot.bat:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %ZOEXT%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%ZOEXT%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" start /d "%ZODIR%" %ZOEXT%
```

If you want i can publish whole code not just segment, it is a cool script :P Just has this small issue.

Only "workaround" i can think is to make the first script, to echo echo in the first file and write the correct system data (this has to be a portable script, so that would work, but would be messy as)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the `%` using `^` if you are in command line.

For example:

```
set var=test
echo %var%
```

echoes `test`

```
set var=test
echo ^%var^%
```

echoes `%var%`

In batch file you have to use double % -

```
set var=1
echo %%var%%
```

echoes `%var%`

Comment: No, you can't escape `%` with `^`, this only works on the cmd-line, but the cause is that there is no variable with the name of `var^` and the expansion works a bit different, than inside of a script

Comment: Better, but not correct :-) Your cmd-line sample fails with `set "var^=content", as the caret isn't an escape character for the percent

Comment: Can you explain? I have verified them to be working. And use my example please, there is no "content" in my example

Answer (score 2):

The `%` can be escaped inside of an batch with a percent.

```
echo %%var%%
```

This doesn't work on the command line, as the parser works there a bit different.
There didn't exists an escape character for the percent, but percents are preseverd if the variable doesn't exist.

```
set "var="
set "var2=content"
echo %var%  %%var2%%
```

results in
    %var% %content%

Answer (score 0):

Just double the percentage signs to escape them, and use carets to escape most other special characters. Here is how I would do it:

```
(echo tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%ZOEXT%%" 2^>NUL ^| find /I /N "%%ZOEXT%%"^>NUL)>>boot.bat
(echo if "%%ERRORLEVEL%%"=="1" start /d "%%ZODIR%%" %%ZOEXT%%)>>boot.bat
```